# Let $L$ be a first order language with equality and two binary function symbols...

Tags: proof-verification, model-theory, first-order-logic

$\bf Question$

> Let $L=(F=\{f^2,g^2\}, P=\{=\}, C=\{c\})$ be a first order language.
>
> Let $I = (\Bbb R^{2\times 2}, f^2(x,y)=(x+y)^t,g^2(x,y)=x+y,0) $ be an interpretation of $L$.
>
> Exhibit a sentence $\alpha$ that has $I$ as a model but that is not universally valid. $\alpha$ must contain at least once each of  $f,c, =$.

$\bf Attempt$

Let $\alpha= \exists x \exists y (\neg x=y \wedge f^2(x,y)=c)$.

Then $I$ is a model of $\alpha$ because it is true by  taking $x=-y, y=I$.

Let $J=(\Bbb N ,f^2(x,y)=x \cdot y,g^2(x,y)= x \cdot y , 1)$

Then $\alpha$ is false because there doesn't exist $x,y, x\neq y$ such that $xy=1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: In your second sentence, you have $A +^t B = (A+B)^t$ but there's no $^t$ operation in the model, no unary functions at all. What is the $^t$ on the RHS supposed to be?

Comment: That's just notation, I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @BrianO Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Ohh, doh, I completely spaced on what the underlying set is. Sure. Yes it's very clear.

Comment: Your sentence is indeed true in $I$ and false in $J$.

Comment: Yes looks good to me.